# Block anything using an IP instead of a domain

Tags: .htaccess, ip, bots, block

Getting a lot of traffic [likely bots] that are hitting my site via an IP address instead of a domain.

For example, a user would access my site at https://www.example.com/login but I'm getting traffic using the IP instead: https://123.45.678.910/login

I would like to block access to anything using the IP instead of the domain. Can this be done via the .htaccess file?

I can do it via PHP, but by then, it's already wasting resources. Is there another / common / best-practice way to handle this?

When googling for the solution, I get a LOT of information about how to block or allow specific IP address(es) or range of IPs, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: The `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable should contain the IP address in that case, so you should be able to block it using something like https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/53821

Comment: Can somehow use it to block an IP pattern?

Comment: Sure, why not - RewriteCond supports regular expressions. But why would you need a pattern, how many IP addresses can your server be reached by?